# Research ideas related to Distributed Single Sign on Systems(ADFS) ?

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs

I'm going to do a research related to Security in Distributed Single Sign On system. Then i came up with the idea of implementing federated security using the LDAP and Kerberos as in following figure.

[Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sutru.png)

Do you think there are any value of doing this kind of research when there is systems like Active Directory Federated Service? What are the disadvantages of systems like ADFS, that i can focus on my research?

P.S: I took above image from http://bigdatamatters.com/bigdatamatters/2010/05/kerberos.html

Comment: If this doesn't get closed for being too broad it should be moved to security.stackexchange.com

Comment: That is pretty much what ADFS does behind, I guess.